# Has null instead of integer/string in the mysql WHERE clause any impact on the performance?

Tags: mysql

for a following query :

```
SELECT some_value 
FROM some_table 
WHERE param_one='62627' 
AND param_two='1' 
AND param_three=QUESTIONABLE_VALUE
```

Does it have any impact on the performance if QUESTIONABLE_VALUE is a null or an integer/string?

Answer (score 0):

[IS NULL Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/is-null-optimization.html). MySQL can perform the same optimization on col_name IS NULL that it can use for col_name = constant_value. For example, MySQL can use indexes and ranges to search for NULL with IS NULL.

You must have a composite index

```
`idx` (`param_one`,`param_two`,`param_three`)
```

Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html#:%7E:text=The%20EXPLAIN%20statement%20provides%20information,about%20the%20statement%20execution%20plan.) to check how the optimizer behave on different datatypes

Comment: I agree that the index is _desirable_, but not "must".  And the order of the columns is not relevant _for this SELECT_.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a parameter that may be null or may be non-null, and you want to match data that is the same, you would use the `<=>` operator (null-safe comparison).

```
SELECT some_value 
FROM some_table 
WHERE param_one='62627' 
AND param_two='1' 
AND param_three <=> QUESTIONABLE_VALUE
```

With `=`, the result will be null if either operand is null.

Answer (score 0):

Your Title, plus the two answers so far, point out issues with testing against `NULL`.  I want to point out an issue with "integer/string".

```
AND param_three = 123
```

can use an index if `param_three` is some numeric type, but not if it a VARCHAR.  The column needs to be converted to numeric to perform the test.

The other way works fine -- these work equally well *if param_two is numeric* because the string literal is converted to numeric.

```
AND param_two='1' 
AND param_two=1
```